# XPath: Compare attributes with other attributes in external file

Tags: xml, xpath, dita

The following code works in DITA if I want to color specific keyword elements in my PDF output, but it's actually not what I want, because the list of attributes is enormously long.

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="keyword">
    <xsl:attribute name="color">
       <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="not(contains('|attr1|attr2|...|attrn|',
                          concat('|', @keyref, '|')))">
          <xsl:value-of select="$kc-darkgrey"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>inherit</xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:attribute-set>
```

I would like to approach the whole thing differently: I want to use an existing external file that contains elements as follows:

```
    <map>
     <title>mytitle</title>
     <keydef keys="alt">
      <topicmeta>
       <keywords>
        <keyword>Alt</keyword>
       </keywords>
      </topicmeta>
     </keydef>
       ...
    </map>
```

My XML file references this external file by referencing the keys attribute with a keyref attribute. My XML file looks like this:

```
<keyword keyref="alt"/>
```

The code at the beginning of my question excludes all keyref attributes of the listed values, but that's IMHO too clumsy as soon as I have more than 20 different attribute values.
Is there a way to create code that says something like: Only color the keywords whose keyref attributes reference/are equal to their corresponding keys in that external file?